# What is an appropriate encounter in Deathwatch

Tags: combat, encounter-design, warhammer-40k, deathwatch

I am wondering how to judge what kind of encounter will be right for my group. I would like to design challenging encounters, but not ones which will be impossible or far too easy. 
How will I know if I can present them with a demon, for example, without killing them outright or whether a horde of chaos heretics is far too easy for them?

I've read [Aramis's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/what-is-an-appropriate-encounter-in-deathwatch) to a similar question, which says:

> EG: PC's average Toughness is 40... so T=4. Average torso armor was 4.
>   Weapon damage was averaging 8 (1d10+2), with Pen 4.
>
> NPC side had T6 and AV8, average damage 7 (1d10+3), pen 0...
>
> PC Side was 8+4 vs 6+8, for -2 NPC side was 7+0 vs 8, for -1.
>   Now, it has to be shifted to positives; move both up the same amount
>   so the lower is +1. In this case, PCs 1, NPC's 2. Now multiply by the
>   numbers. I had 7 PC's, and used 4 NPC's... for 7 and 8. Then multiply
>   by average skill as a percentage... PC average was 45, NPC was 33, for
>   7*0.45=3.15 and 8*0.33= 2.64. It's clear the PC's have an advantage,
>   but a very weak one... and since in the initial stage, both were
>   negatives, it's going to involve a lot of armor staging.

But I don't understand why he's multiplied the PCs' WS with the NPC damage (or at least that is what it looks like for me). Can anyone explain this more clearly?

Comment: I am not sure if the answer fully addresses my problem as I don't fully understand it. I have asked in Meta what to do and have been told to do exactly what I have done here. I am happy for a different solution, if I am going about the problem the wrong way.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie would it be possible for you to add an answer to the meta question relating to this if you disagree with the above approach? http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/what-if-someone-asked-my-question-and-it-has-been-answered-but-i-dont-understa